# Deportees from Australia to UK early 1900's

Tags: united-kingdom, australia, deportation-records

I am trying to confirm the claim that a relative was deported form Australia back to UK in the early 1900's.

I can find any number of sources for people being transported from UK to Australia but nothing for deportees headed in the other direction.

Does anybody know if records were kept of such things and, if so, where those records are held?

Comment: Hi Ian, welcome to G&FH SE! Transportation to Australia ended in the 1860s. Presumably your ancestor committed a fairly serious crime to be deported - in which case I'd start looking for details about the crime rather than jumping to deportation records. It may also help to know how and when he got to Australia, I'm assuming he wasn't transported then deported 40+ years later...

Comment: If your ancestor was deported, he presumably was not Australian-born, so there may be an immigration record for his entry at an earlier date. That would give a date range for residence, and might help tie him to a particular place in Aus.

Comment: Hi, Ian, welcome to G&FH.SE!  I agree with the other answers and comments -- establish the best timeline you can and try to narrow down the possible date of deportation as much as possible. You can add information to your question if you like, using the edit link under your question.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible sets of records to search.

Firstly, the [National Archives of Australia](http://www.naa.gov.au/) holds online departure records from various ports.

Although incomplete for the early 1900s, and not specifically for deportees, this may help start your search.

In my experience, the responses to their [Enquiry Form](http://www.naa.gov.au/collection/askquestion/index.aspx) are very helpful in narrowing down your search.  Initial enquiries are free.

Secondly, the court records to find the sentence of deportation.
Court records are more commonly kept by the Public Record Offices of the individual states.  (e.g. [Victoria](https://www.prov.vic.gov.au/explore-collection/explore-topic/justice-crime-and-law)).  Records of deportation are more likely to be held at these locations.

Unless you can narrow down the date, you may have a very long search on your hands.